# setAdapter is not calling getView.

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked several times, but the solutions have been specific to the askers' problems. Consequently, none of those solutions helped me, even though I tried following all of their suggestions.

So here goes.

I have a movies Activity like this. Notice that I have a `MoviesAdapter` inner class, that's supposed to populate the `moviesDisplay` `ListView`.

```
package com.example.midtermexam;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MoviesActivity extends Activity {
    public String url;

    public ListView moviesDisplay;
    public static ArrayList<Movie> thisMovies;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);
        url=getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        moviesDisplay = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        new AsyncMoviesGet(this).execute(url);


    }

    public void populateListView()
    {


        Log.d("listview","adapter created");

        Log.d("listview","Listview declared");
        Log.d("listview","adapter populated");
        moviesDisplay.setAdapter(new MoviesListAdapter());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.movies, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class MoviesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {
        public MoviesListAdapter() {
            super(MoviesActivity.this, R.layout.movies_activity_listview, thisMovies);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
            View movieView = convertView;
            if (movieView == null) {
                movieView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.movies_activity_listview, parent, false);
            }

            // Find the car to work with.


            return movieView;
        }               
    }

}
```

The populateListView() method is called from an AsyncTask called AsyncMoviesGet, whose postExecute() looks like this.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Movie> result) {
        if(result != null){

            m.thisMovies = result;
            m.populateListView();
            Log.d("demo", result.toString());
        } else{
            Log.d("demo", "null result");
        }

    }
```

You can see the Log messages inside the `populateListView()` method. These 3 statements get executed. However, the `setAdapter()` function doesn't seem to call the "`GetView`" function.

Comment: Can you show your AsyncTask?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's kinda confidential. Besides, I can assure you, the rest of the program is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Add stuff to `ArrayAdapter` at least, use `mAdapter.addAll()`:

```
private MoviesListAdapter mAdapter;

. . . . . .

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  . . . . . 
  mAdapter = new MoviesListAdapter();
  moviesDisplay.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

. . . . .

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Movie> result) {
    if(result != null){

        m.thisMovies = result;

        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(result);
        mAdapter.notifyDatasetInvalidated();

        Log.d("demo", result.toString());
    } else{
        Log.d("demo", "null result");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a constructor to your Custom Adapter class, one that takes a context, resource id & a data structure containing the items you'd like to display, in this case your thisMovies.

```
public MoviesListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, 
                         ArrayList<String> viewItems)
{
    super(context, resourceId, viewItems);
}
```

Then you have to construct your adapter based on the results you've received in your onPostExecute().  Before this is done, create an instance variable in the activity which will be used to store the adapter.

```
MoviesListAdapter mMovieAdapter = null;
```

Afterwards, construct it by changing this

```
moviesDisplay.setAdapter(new MoviesListAdapter());
```

to something like below

```
if(thisMovies != null && thisMovies.size() > 0) { 
    mMovieAdapter = new MoviesListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.movies_activity_listview, thisMovies);
    moviesDisplay.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
} else { 
    Log.w("MyApplication","onPostExecute() did not return any items!");
}
```

Comment: 1) Constructor already there. Please check.
2) Check. Created instance variable. Initiated in PopulateListView() method which is called in postExecute.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise and call adapter by this way..........this is just an e.g. you need to modify it according to your controls:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(container.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textview1);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And inside the custom adapter class, its constructor should also have these kind of parameters:

```
public ListViewAdapter(Context context,int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<YourObjectType> items) {
    super(context,resource,textViewResourceId, items);
    this.context1 = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Comment: Hello all, I really appreciate your answer. But it turns out, I had made an extremely silly mistake. I forgot to add the ListView on the layout. :P

Comment: calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); before setting the adapter is not useful. Also, when you call setAdapter, the list is actually reset and redrawn, so it is quite useless to make the call at all if you are simply resetting the adapter for the list.